# Why there stays an Excel process open after OLE object quit?

Tags: excel, delphi, ole

I am trying to save data within a Delphi application as an excel-file.
I use an OLEobject but have the problem that an Excel process stays open.

I need additional worksheets and depending on how I add them the process will be closed or not.
See the code.

The excel processes will be always closed after I close my application (but not earlier).
Where is the problem with code version1?

Btw. I use Delphi 10.2.3 & Excel 2010, Windows 7

```
var
  lExcel        : OLEVariant;
  lMyWorkbook   : OLEVariant;
  lMyWorkSheets : OLEVariant;
begin
  try
    lExcel := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  except
    exit;
  end;
  lExcel.visible := true;

  lMyWorkbook   := lExcel.Workbooks.Add;
  lMyWorkSheets := lMyWorkbook.WorkSheets;

  //adding another worksheet 
  //version1 - insert at the end of the list 
  //the excel process stays open after quit
  lMyWorkSheets.Add( After:=lMyWorkbook.Worksheets[ lMyWorkSheets.Count ] );

  //version2 - insert before active worksheet
  //the excel process will be closed after quit
  lMyWorkSheets.Add;


  lMyWorkSheets:=unassigned;
  lMyWorkbook.Close;
  lMyWorkbook:=unassigned;

  lExcel.Quit;
  lExcel:=unassigned;
end;
```

Comment: FWIW, I cannot replicate the problem. I'm using Delphi XE7, Excel 2007 and Win 7

Comment: I tested also with Excel 2013 and had the same problem, So I am guessing that the newer version of Delphi is causing that problem.

Answer (score 1):

By trial and error I found out how to solve my problem:

Instead of

```
lMyWorkSheets.Add( After:=lMyWorkbook.Worksheets[ lMyWorkSheets.Count ] );
```

which was adapted from the MS VBA help
(https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.sheets.add)

I have to use

```
LastWorkSheet := lMyWorkbook.Worksheets[ lMyWorkSheets.Count ];
lMyWorkSheets.Add( After := LastWorkSheet );
```